# Should tags 'ssl' and 'tls' be separate since SSLv3 vulnerability discovery? Information about merged tags would be great too

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

As I noticed for now these tags are merged and merging these tags now seems like it was bad idea since it merged all tls/ssl related questions and there is problem to distinct one from the other, or it is since now when we live in no SSLv3 reality.

Nice thing would be also (unless i missed it somehow) to display what tags are merged to whhich 'main tag'. I did edited my question two times wondering why does **tls** disappears from list of tags. I got enlighted just when i tried to go to **tls** tag listing by hand.

Answer (score 3):

Could they should be separate? Probably. They are different underlying technologies that developers deal with. Also the synonym was created in 2011 and things have changed.

But there is a branding problem at play here too. You buy an SSL certificates from a certificate authority. You don't buy a TLS certificate because of the branding that the certificate authorities have used. Also many people will see `https` and say "it's using SSL".

While I do think they could be separated, I think [ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssl) will continue to be the catch all until the culture changes a bit more. Or if someone really knows what they are talking about and knows it should be [tls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tls) (like in your case).